# Finding attributes of individual plots generated in a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to work out the gradient and the correlation index of the graphs I have created from a dataframe. There should be a graph produced from each column of the dataframe. To get the graphs I have used this code:

```
for(c in names(x15.sub))
print(ggplot(data=x15.sub) + geom_point(aes(x = x15.sub[[c]], y = T8641))
    + geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(x = x15.sub[[c]], y = T8641))+ labs(x=c))
```

I think I need to use the command 'attributes' to get the gradient, but I can't work out where to out it in the code, as each graph seems to be generated without a 'name'. 
I also can't work out how to save the graphs. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you include a small amount of data from `x15.sub` please?

Comment: Either calculate the `lm` data outside the `ggplot` call or retrieve it from the object created.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to calculate it outside of the ggplot.